# How to redirect user to login page with Laravel when template request returns 401 redirect

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I have an angularjs/laravel web application where template includes are loaded dynamically.

The problem is that when a user's session times out and they navigate to a new section on the page, it will make a redirect on the server side and actually serve back the login page where the template should have been.

How can I intercept this template request and instead redirect the user to the login page instead of simply returning the login page as a template?

Answer (score 0):

On one project we used this way of intercepting http errors. There you can redirect to login page (or whatever you like).

```
function httpInterceptor($provide, $httpProvider) {
    function interceptorFunction($q) {
        return {
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                if (typeof rejection.status !== 'undefined') {
                    if (rejection.status === 401) {
                        //Your app will handle 401 errors here... 
                    } 
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }

    $provide.factory('httpInterceptor', interceptorFunction);
    interceptorFunction.$injector = ['$q'];
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');

 angular.module('app', dependencies)
    .config(httpInterceptor);
```

'app' module is our 'main' module. The 401 error should happen though so server should at least once respond with that status code.

Comment: Okay thanks. I actually just implemented this and haven't yet tested it. But would this intercept the laravel request as well? i.e. does it intercept all http requests instead of just the ones made through the $http service?

Comment: this will for sure intercept every $http request. I am not aware that you could make ajax call from angular app that will not use $http. $resource is dependant on $http also... If you make a vanilla javascript call it might not catch it (but why)